# How to stop slf4j printing a pointless information message at startup?

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm not using SLF4J myself, but some Apache library that I'm using has it as a dependency. (I've installed the latest version: `2.1.0-alpha1`).

I have added the corresponding `slf4j-nop` library on my classpath, and now instead of complaining that there's no SLF4J implementation, it prints to STDERR the following message:

```
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [org.slf4j.nop.NOPServiceProvider]
```

It's an information message saying it's found my NOP provider. How can I get rid of this pointlessly irritating message? I did a Google search for the message but came up with no hits.

I would prefer not to redirect STDERR or anything weird like that if I can help it. Surely, there must be a built-in way to stop this message from printing?

Comment: Are you not interested in this specific INFO message or not interested in *any* INFO message (like increasing the log level to WARN)?

Comment: I mean it's this specific message that I find irritating, but really I don't want any messages (hence why I'm using the NOP implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I ended up reading the slf4j source code, and it turns out you can turn off this message by setting the `slf4j.internal.verbosity` system property to `WARN`.

I just put this at the start of my main method:

```java
System.setProperty("slf4j.internal.verbosity", "WARN");
```

Comment: Interestingly, it was changed in [commit 8f8691065dc432f1d47b1307610e447c37d52ef8 at Dec 18, 2023](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/commit/8f8691065dc432f1d47b1307610e447c37d52ef8#diff-204f23f1c787a5f1f6162f79eae7d8694d723ef7788e23b79ed270a15c677b00). Not sure why the `isAmbiguousProviderList()` check was removed...